# Unable to Build node rdkafka on Apple M1 air

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, apple-m1, librdkafka

I am trying to run npm install node-rdkafka on my m1 air but I am getting this build error.

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'fabric-ca-client@2.2.5',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10.15.3 || ^12.13.1 || ^14.13.1', npm: '^6.4.1' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.14.0', npm: '7.7.6' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'fabric-common@2.2.5',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10.15.3 || ^12.13.1 || ^14.13.1', npm: '^6.4.1' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.14.0', npm: '7.7.6' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'fabric-network@2.2.5',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10.15.3 || ^12.13.1 || ^14.13.1', npm: '^6.4.1' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.14.0', npm: '7.7.6' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'fabric-protos@2.2.5',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^10.15.3 || ^12.13.1 || ^14.13.1', npm: '^6.4.1' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.14.0', npm: '7.7.6' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/karan/Documents/interchain data/interchain_app/node_modules/node-rdkafka
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! ACTION deps_librdkafka_gyp_librdkafka_target_configure deps/librdkafka/config.h
npm ERR! Usage: ./configure [OPTIONS...]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!  mklove configure script - mklove, not autoconf
npm ERR!  Copyright (c) 2014-2019 Magnus Edenhill - https://github.com/edenhill/mklove
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!  librdkafka - The Apache Kafka C/C++ library
npm ERR!  Copyright (c) 2012-2019 Magnus Edenhill
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Development options:
npm ERR!    --enable-devel                       Enable development asserts, checks, etc [n]
npm ERR!    --disable-devel                      Disable development asserts, checks, etc
npm ERR!    --enable-valgrind                    Enable in-code valgrind suppressions [n]
npm ERR!    --disable-valgrind                   Disable in-code valgrind suppressions
npm ERR!    --enable-refcnt-debug                Enable refcnt debugging [n]
npm ERR!    --disable-refcnt-debug               Disable refcnt debugging
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Feature options:
npm ERR!    --enable-lz4-ext                     Enable external LZ4 library support (builtin version 1.9.2) [y]
npm ERR!    --disable-lz4-ext                    Disable external LZ4 library support (builtin version 1.9.2)
npm ERR!    --enable-lz4                         Deprecated: alias for --enable-lz4-ext [y]
npm ERR!    --disable-lz4                        Deprecated: alias for --enable-lz4-ext
npm ERR!    --enable-regex-ext                   Enable external (libc) regex (else use builtin) [y]
npm ERR!    --disable-regex-ext                  Disable external (libc) regex (else use builtin)
npm ERR!    --enable-c11threads                  Enable detection of C11 threads support in libc [try]
npm ERR!    --disable-c11threads                 Disable detection of C11 threads support in libc
npm ERR!    --enable-syslog                      Enable logging to syslog [y]
npm ERR!    --disable-syslog                     Disable logging to syslog
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Honoured environment variables:
npm ERR!   CC, CPP, CXX, CFLAGS, CPPFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, LDFLAGS, LIBS,
npm ERR!   LD, NM, OBJDUMP, STRIP, PKG_CONFIG, PKG_CONFIG_PATH,
npm ERR!   STATIC_LIB_<libname>=.../libname.a
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.14.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.5 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/karan/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/karan/Documents/interchain data/interchain_app/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/karan/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/karan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.14.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/karan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.14.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/karan/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/karan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.14.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/karan/Documents/interchain data/interchain_app/node_modules/node-rdkafka',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: data/interchain_app/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/Release/lib.host:/Users/karan/Documents/interchain: No such file or directory
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 957: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 957: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module builtin from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.builtin
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download builtin:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module builtin not found (required by base)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module host from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.host
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download host:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module host not found (required by base)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module cc from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.cc
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download cc:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module cc not found (required by base)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 957: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module cxx from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.cxx
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download cxx:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module cxx not found (required by self)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module lib from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.lib
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download lib:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module lib not found (required by self)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module pic from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.pic
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download pic:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module pic not found (required by self)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module atomics from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.atomics
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download atomics:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module atomics not found (required by self)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module good_cflags from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.good_cflags
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download good_cflags:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module good_cflags not found (required by self)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module socket from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.socket
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download socket:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module socket not found (required by self)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module zlib from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.zlib
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download zlib:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module zlib not found (required by self)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module libzstd from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.libzstd
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download libzstd:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module libzstd not found (required by self)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module libssl from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.libssl
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download libssl:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module libssl not found (required by self)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module libsasl2 from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.libsasl2
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download libsasl2:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module libsasl2 not found (required by self)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! downloading missing module parseversion from http://github.com/edenhill/mklove/raw/master/modules/configure.parseversion
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 983: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Failed to download parseversion:
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1973: wget: command not found
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 974: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Module parseversion not found (required by self)
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! Unknown option prefix=/Users/karan/Documents/interchain data/interchain_app/node_modules/node-rdkafka/build/deps
npm ERR! mklove/modules/configure.base: line 966: $MKL_OUTDBG: ambiguous redirect
npm ERR! make: *** No rule to make target `../deps/librdkafka/config.h', needed by `11a9e3388a67e1ca5c31c1d8da49cb6d2714eb41.intermediate'.  Stop.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/karan/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/karan/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/bin/node" "/Users/karan/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/karan/Documents/interchain data/interchain_app/node_modules/node-rdkafka
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/karan/.npm/_logs/2021-06-02T12_08_12_312Z-debug.log
```

I have the latest version of node installed compatible with the M1 chip. All the other node packages i needed installed fine. Also I even tried installing the librdkafka library using homebrew and it did not help either.
What am I doing wrong here ??

Comment: Did you try reverting to Node v14? Seems like Node v15 is not supported by some of your dependencies. More broadly, you shouldn't use odd-numbered version of Node as they become quickly unsupported, see here https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

Comment: no i did not try reverting back to node v14 as it needs rosetta 2 but node v15 natively supports m1.

Comment: Well, I think you might very well be stuck here, since `fabric` packages seems to support up to Node v14.13... Try removing these (if you can) and see if it changes anything.

Comment: you know what i removed the node-rdkafka from my package.json but did not remove the fabric modules and the npm install was successful. So though we see a warning for fabric modules they installed fine but the problem is node-rdkafka.

Comment: Ok, that's a bit weird.. Try looking at the issues listed in their GitHub repo then, I cannot help further...

Answer (score 0):

Switch to node 14 (14.19.1) was solution for me.

Comment: Node version is not the direct cause for this issue